# How can I use my global vars in a custom adapter in Android?

Tags: android, variables, global, adapter

I created a class extending Application to have global variables in my app. I use them using

```
((GlobalVars)getApplicationContext())
```

but this does not compile when I'm trying to access it in my custom adapter:

```
The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type FriendAdapter
```

Why? How can I access my global vars in my adapter?

Thanks

---

GlobalVars

```
public class GlobalVars extends Application {

    private ArrayList<String> selectFriendList = new ArrayList<String>();  

    public void addSelectedFriend(String fb_id) {
        this.selectFriendList.add(fb_id);       
    }

    public void removeSelectedFriend(String fb_id) {
        this.selectFriendList.remove(fb_id);        
    }

    public boolean isFriendSelected(String fb_id) {
        return this.selectFriendList.contains(fb_id);       
    }
}
```

FriendAdapter

```
public class FriendAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> implements OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<Friend> items;   

    public FriendAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Friend> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.contact_row, null);
        }
        Friend f = items.get(position);
        if (f != null) {

            String name = f.name;
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            tt.setText(name);        

            CheckBox bCheck = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            bCheck.setTag(f.fb_id);

            if (((GlobalVars)getApplicationContext()).isFriendSelected(f.fb_id))
                bCheck.setChecked(true);

            bCheck.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep a private member variable referencing the context within your Adapter class:

```
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Friend> items;   

public FriendAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<Friend> items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

Then get a handle to your application context from the context variable:

```
if (((GlobalVars) mContext.getApplicationContext()).isFriendSelected(f.fb_id))
            bCheck.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter isn't a context, so you can't get Application from this class. But you can write ArrayAdapter's implementation in Activity(it is context). Something like this, when you initialize adapter:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> A = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_view, 
                    new String[]{"1", "2"}){
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//get view implementation                   
return convertView;
                }
            };
```